# How can evaluate $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{3x^2}{\tan(x)\sin(x)}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I know this
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{3x^2}{\tan(x)\sin(x)}$$
But I have no idea how make a result different of:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{3x}{\tan(x)}$$
I would like understand this calculation without using derivation or L'hôpital's rule. Thank you.

Comment: This _is_ kinda related to your earlier question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421473/how-can-evaluate-lim-x-to0-frac-sin3x2-tanx-sinx , and can be calculated by similar means...

Comment: I can't understand how come you ask this new question after you asked, and were answered galore, another very similar question: can't you compare?!

Comment: So, I would put this remark in the header, but as I am still beginner as a user, I am trying to learn what is relevant or not, but I tried to learn how to do without the sine, but I could not see, but I'm learning new techniques, basically was by this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\tan x = \dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}$, we have the identity:

$$\frac{3x^2}{\tan x\sin x} = \frac{3x^2\cos x}{\sin^2 x}$$

valid in at least an open, punctured neighbourhood around $0$.

Now using the product rule for limits, and that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}x = 1$ (proofs [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/75130/43351), also some without differentiation):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{3x^2}{\tan x\sin x} = \lim_{x\to0}\cos x\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3x^2}{\sin^2 x} = 3$$

Comment: thank you very much, I could understand your calculations, and i made myself

Answer (score 4):

By Taylor series we have $\tan x\sim_0 x$ hence
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{3x}{\tan(x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{3x}{x}=3$$

Comment: You cannot always make substitutions like this, right? For example, if you have the limit as x approaches 0 of $\frac {tan(x)-x}{x^3}$ this is equal to $1/3$, but if you were to make your substitution, you would get $0$.

Comment: Only when it is a multiplier on the whole limit.

Comment: Very nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

Replace $\tan x$ by $\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$. Our expression becomes
$$3(\cos x)\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^2. $$
You are undoubtedly familiar with the fact that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**

$$\frac{3x^{2}}{\tan x\sin x}=3\times \frac{x}{\tan x}\times \frac{x}{\sin x},$$

$$$$

$$0<x<\frac{\pi }{2}\Rightarrow \sin x<x<\tan x\Leftrightarrow 1<\frac{x}{
\sin x}<\frac{1}{\cos x}.$$

Answer (score 0):

We have, 
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{ x^2 }{\tan(x)\sin(x)} =3\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{\sin(x)}\cdot\frac{x}{\tan(x)} =3$$

Given that $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin  h}{h} =\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\tan  h}{h} =1$$